# How to search for a percent symbol (%) in Vim?

Tags: vim, replace

I'm trying to do a global find and replace for old-style PHP tags that look like this:

```
<%= $username %>
```

However when I try to do a search and replace in Vim, I get an "E71: Invalid character after \%" warning, and a "E476: Invalid command" warning:

```
:%s/\<\%/other val/c
```

I've also tried:

```
:%s/\<\\%/other val/c     " two escapes, returns no matches
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing in this search needs escaping, `:%s/<%/<?php/g` works precisely as expected, replacing `<%` with `<?php` everywhere.

Comment: I wanted to remove all `%` from my text. I noticed that I wrote `:s/\%//g`. Focusing on "%" as data must have made me forget to use the `%` that always comes before `s` as part of the command. Funny effect.